# Google Sheets function to rename sheet to equal cell value

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get my sheet names to equal cell values, whether it be text or numbers, but I've come up short.
After numerous google searches, and testing, this is as close as I've gotten to an answer.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2")
  sheets[3].setName(cell);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that there are restrictions on valid names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to getValue[¹](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) from the range you got.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; //Sheet 2
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");//Sheet2!A2    
  var value = cell.getValue();//Added
  sheet.setName(value);//Sheet2 name changed
}
```

Comment: This works great for a single sheet! But is there a way - ok, I'm sure there is, but I don't know how... - to repeat this renaming process for all sheets (let's say starting from the 2nd sheet on) ??

Comment: @zenortheartofregex `getSheets()` returns a array. Use a for loop or `Array.forEach()`. If you're having trouble implementing, ask a new  question.