# Dynamic sheet name change bases on a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to get the current month weeks number on this range C3:C8. Based on that values, to rename the following tabs names: Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8

Also, I would like this script to work only on sheet name: Sheet1

Is there a google script that can acomplish this request?
I would really appreciate it.
Thank you very much!

[image]

```js
function sheetsNames(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var values = sh.getRange('C3:C8').getValues()
  for (var i=values.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    ss.getSheets()[i+3].setName(values[i][0])
  }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE: I'm trying to attach the function renameSheetTabs() into a drawing but for some reason I'm getting the following error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

You can try this script structure below:

### Script

```
function renameSheetTabs(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var values = sh.getRange('C3:C8').getValues();
  var startTab = 2; //first tab will be sheet #2 or the tab after "Sheet1"
  for (var i=0; i<startTab;i++){
    if(values.length == i)return; //loop will stop once all tabs have been renamed
      Logger.log(ss.getSheets()[i+2].getName()+" To \""+values[i] +"\"\nRenaming Done!");
      ss.getSheets()[i+2].setName(values[i]);
    }catch{
      return;
    }
    startTab += 1;
  }
}
```

### Sample Demonstration

- Test Sheet:

> [image]

- After running the script:

> [image]

- Execution logs for review

> [image]

Comment: @mau the script above will loop though the sheet tabs after `Sheet1` and beyond one-by-one then rename them based on each values from range `C3:C8` on `Sheet1`. I hope it helps.

Comment: This one is working very well but the I cannot add the script into a drawing (button). Also, the script takes some time to execute in the sheet? Because it takes like 5 to 10 minutes to be updated in the sheet itself.
UPDATE: Ok, seems like I have to run it twice

Comment: @mau You can add the script function into a drawing button by clicking the three dots on the image & select `Assign script` like this [sample image](https://imgur.com/a/fnv6wUt). That is expected to slow down in case you are renaming multiple sheet tabs using the script. Since your are renaming specific sheet tabs, we can't use the [Use batch operations | Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) to speed up the process since we can't put the sheet tabs into an array & do the renaming of sheet tabs all at once.

Comment: @mau I'm glad that this implementation works on your end. You may also you want to click the `accept`/`up-vote` button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may `have the same concern as you`, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509776/google-sheets-function-to-rename-sheet-to-equal-cell-value) that has a code that answer this question:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; //Sheet 2
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");//Sheet2!A2    
  var value = cell.getValue();//Added
  sheet.setName(value);//Sheet2 name changed
}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) is the Google Documentation.

Comment: What about the other tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function sheetsNames(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var values = sh.getRange('C3:C8').getValues()
  for (var i=values.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    ss.getSheets()[i+3].setName(values[i][0])
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works!! But how can I get the current month week numbers in the range C3:C8?

Comment: Also, since the names in the tabs will dimaycally change, this part will not work ss.getSheetByName('Sheet'+(i+3))

Comment: ok, I have amended my answer

Comment: I get an error which I have attached to this post, but for some reason is not working since I need to set the names of the following sheets after the position of Sheet1

Comment: you didn't get enough sheets ? pls be more explicit in your demand as you wrote Sheet3 etc. and not third sheet!